# Codename one, How can i achieve this User Interface?

Tags: codenameone

I came across this app from google groups, They say its done with codenameone.
Does anyone have an idea how they achieved this UI. It doesnt look like the cn1 default UI. 
Please see the google play store link if you can.
[Playstore link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.forann.FMap_App)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's the default ComboBox UI when running under Android 2.x with the native theme. To see how this was styled you can open the Android 2.x native theme file from our git repository (`androidTheme.res`) https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/tree/master/Themes

Comment: I tried to open the file in netbeans, I get. Fatal error loading the resources File. Corrupt theme file unrecognise magic number:a

Comment: Make sure you downloaded the raw file and didn't just download the HTML representing the file with a right click save as.